# Use of OS styles and rgba in CSS

Tags: css

Specifically, I have a CSS property `border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);`. I want to make the color change, but leave the opacity alone. The color also would be a property named `Highlight` ([using OS styles](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-system-styles/)).

How is this possible, if it even is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, or at least not with a named color.

You should use `rgba()` or `hsla()` in order to be able to control the opacity.